# NodeJS: Returning image from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get object from S3. It is an image. The issue is I get data object from S3 but don't know how to convert it into image/jpeg. Here is my code:

```
s3.getObject(_params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        return res.end(JSON.stringify({ responseMessage: 'An error occured!' }));
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        //here I need to return response as image/jpeg
    }
});
```

Could not find anything related to this on AWS documentation. How do we do this?

Comment: may you paste the data that you are getting from s3, meaning the console.log(data); and update the comment.

Comment: Is your objective is to return the image in private bucket to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the data to an xxx.jpeg file you would be able to open it as a JPEG image. You should be able to write it out as you would any content:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
res.end(data); // Send the file data to the browser.
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to specify that you are returning binary data:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
res.write(data,'binary');
res.end(null, 'binary');
```